# Detect when a user is in a specific location

Tags: java, android, location

If I have a restaurant app for example that just orders some food. Is it possible to detect when one of my app users enters the store and then the app does something? For example when the user comes in the app sends a notification or opens up the menu. Also can this be done while the app is neither running on the background nor visually visible?

Comment: I'd suggest starting with your own online research on the topic, and then coming back to Stackoverflow with more specific questions, instead of the other way around. Anyone answering this question will essentially be doing your research for you.

Comment: @Egor I did a research and I didn't find anything useful.